Evaluating: $ \int_0^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{\alpha}{\kappa}\left(\sqrt{p^2+1}-1\right)\right]^{-\kappa-1} p^2 \,dp $
I try to evaluate the following integral :
$$
\operatorname{I}\left(\kappa,\alpha\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\left[1 + \frac{\alpha}{\kappa}\left(\sqrt{\,{p^{2} + 1}\,} - 1\right)\right]^{-\kappa - 1}\,p^{2}{\rm d}p
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\kappa$ are real constants which can have the values :
$$
\kappa=0.1,\ 1,\ 10,\ 1000\quad\mbox{and}\quad \alpha=0.1,\ 1,\ 10,\ 100,\ 1000
$$
This integral is necessary when we try to evaluate the particle number density $n$ of a plasma with a kappa equilibrium distribution function
$\operatorname{f}\left(\kappa,p,\alpha\right)$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{f}\left(\kappa,p,\alpha\right) & =
n\,C\left[1 + \frac{\alpha}{\kappa}\left(\sqrt{p^{2} + 1} - 1\right)\right]^{-\kappa - 1}
\\[2mm]
\operatorname{n}\left(\kappa,\alpha\right) & =
4\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{f}\left(\kappa,p,\alpha\right)\,p^{2}{\rm d}p
\end{align}
where $C$ is a constant of normalisation.
Any advice, hint or well-thought solution will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

What value have $\kappa$ and $\alpha$? What physical phenomenon is the integral calculated analytically?

Mathematica gives solution with sum of 9 gauss hypergeometric function.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk I tried the calculation with Mathematica 14, but it didn't work. Do you have the result please?

Try: (1/2)*c^3*m^3*(1/\[Kappa])^(-1 - \[Kappa])*Integrate[(\[Alpha]*Sqrt[x] - \[Alpha] + \[Kappa])^(-1 - \[Kappa])*Sqrt[x - 1], {x, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {\[Kappa] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}]

Try $\displaystyle p = mc,\sinh\left(\theta\right)$

@Mariusz Iwaniuk Thank you so much. Is there a possibility of doing this analytically? A possibility to simplify it more?

I have simpler solutions with one MeijerG function,but You didn't answer my first question about physical phenmenon and values of kappa and alfa?

@Mariusz Iwaniuk this integral is involved in the calculation of the plasma density where the particle distribution function is a kappa function $ f(κ,p)$ with $κ=0.1, 1, 10, 1000$ and $\alpha=0.1,  1, 10, 100, 1000$.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk Do you have the simplified solution with MeijerG?

@
Mariusz Iwaniuk  what question are you talking about? I didn't delete any questions

@Xander Henderson Why you deleted Mariusz's answer? I didn't delete any questions. Please restore it.

A comment on it said “Deleted by request of the author. –
Xander Henderson♦”. The author here is Mariusz. Is it true that it was asked to be deleted? Also, his comment asking you about it is now deleted.

@Тyma Gaidash
but I did not ask to delete the answer, it was me who asked the question in this post.

@Gallager I don't know who will delete my answer, maybe there was an matrix error :P. I can't get "Undelete post". I don't have the rights that a moderator has. Regards.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk Why don't the moderators intervene? I ask that they restore
Mariusz's answer. Thank you so much Mariusz!

Denote the integral by $I(\kappa, \alpha)$.
As $p \to \infty$ the integrand has the asymptotic form $\left(\frac\kappa\alpha\right)^{1 + \kappa} p^{1 - \kappa} + \cdots$, where $\cdots$ denotes an error term of decay $p^{-\kappa}$, so the $I(\kappa, \alpha)$ only converges when $\kappa > 2$.
The substitution $p = \frac{2 t}{1 - t^2}$ transforms the integral to $$I(\kappa, \alpha) = 8 \kappa^{\kappa + 1} \int_0^1 \frac{(1 - t^2)^{\kappa - 3} t^2 (1 + t^2) \,dt}{((2 \alpha - \kappa) t^2 + \kappa)^{1 + \kappa}} ,$$
and Maple can evaluate this integral in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1$ and the gamma function, but the closed form is a mess and not worth reproducing here. That said, we can say a few things that might be useful.

The integrand of the integral in $t$ is rational for integers $\kappa$, which makes closed-form expressions in terms of elementary functions possible. For example, for $\kappa = 3$, the integral has value
$$I(3, \alpha) = \frac{3 \sqrt 3 \alpha}{(2 \alpha - 3)^{\frac52}} \arctan \sqrt\frac{2 \alpha - 3}{3} + \frac{9 (\alpha - 3)(\alpha^2 + 4 \alpha + 6)}{2 \alpha^3 (2 \alpha - 3)^2}$$ if $\alpha > \frac32$, and a similar expression involving $\operatorname{artanh}$ applies when $0 < \alpha < \frac32$. As $\alpha \searrow 0$, $I(3, \alpha) \sim 9 \alpha^{-3} + \cdots$, where $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O(\alpha^{-2})$. As $\alpha \to \infty$, $I(3, \alpha) \sim \frac{3 \sqrt 3 \pi}{8 \sqrt 2} \alpha^{-\frac32} + \cdots$, where $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O(\alpha^{\frac52})$. For half-integer $\kappa$ we can expect closed forms in terms of complete elliptic integral functions.

The form of the integral in $t$ suggests that the integral simplifies in the special cases $\alpha = \kappa, \frac12\kappa$. In the former case it has value
$$I(\kappa, \kappa) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}4 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac\kappa2-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac\kappa2 + \frac12\right)} .$$ As $\kappa \searrow 2$, $I(\kappa, \kappa) \sim (\kappa - 2)^{-1} + (\log 2 - 1) + \cdots$, where the $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O(\kappa - 2)$. As $\kappa \to \infty$, $I(\kappa, \kappa) \sim \sqrt\frac\pi2 \kappa^{-\frac32} + \cdots$, where $\cdots$ denotes terms of $O(\kappa^{-\frac52})$. Similar formulas apply to the case $\alpha = \frac12 \kappa$.

In the limit as $\kappa \searrow 2$,
$$I(\kappa, \alpha) \sim \frac{8}{\alpha^3} \cdot \frac{1}{\kappa - 2} + \cdots,$$ where $\cdots$ denotes terms of $O(1)$.

In the limit as $\kappa \to \infty$, we have
$$\lim_{\kappa \to \infty} I(\kappa, \alpha) = \int_0^\infty p^2 e^{-\alpha \left(\sqrt{p^2 + 1} - 1\right)} \,dp ,$$
which is expressible in terms of $K_\alpha(1)$, where $K_\alpha$ is a Modified Bessel Functions of the Second Kind, and its second derivative with respect to $\alpha$.

For fixed $\kappa$, expanding in a series about $\alpha = \infty$ gives the asymptotic expansion
$$I(\kappa, \alpha) \sim \sqrt\frac\pi2 \kappa^{\frac32} \frac{\Gamma(\kappa - \frac12)}{\Gamma\left(\kappa + 1\right)} \alpha^{-\frac32} + \cdots ,$$ where $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O\left(\alpha^{-\frac52}\right).$



@ Travis Willse thank you very much for these explanations, although I am looking for the exact solution of the integral, your analysis helps a lot. Can you give me the analytical solution you find with Maple (which I don't have) in terms of the hypergeometric function 2F1
and the gamma function?

It's too long to typeset in a comment, but see here for a screencap: https://i.imgur.com/phgtfmZ.png

@ Travis Willse thank you so much.

@Gallagher It looks like Mariusz has added a much more compact closed form to his answer. I suggest that you accept his when you are ready.
